# Magento 2.3.1 MFTF command error Permissin denied

Tags: error, magento2.3, mftf

I am working on the MFTF concept in Magento 2.3 community version.
 I am trying to run commands like **`vendor/bin/mftf --version`** and **`vendor/bin/mftf build:project`**, but getting error every time as:

> -" -bash: vendor/bin/mftf: Permission denied "

In vendor/bin I am trying to run command mftf --version . but it is also showing no command 'mtft' found.

Please provide a solution.  What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the read write permissions? have you tried to sudo up

Comment: Yes, I have checked the read write permissions. They are fine , 775 to vendor, bin and mftf .

Answer (score 0):

chmod +x vendor/bin/mftf
*assign the permission for this folder by using this command*